# "Syntax error" word unexpected

Tags: bash, syntax-error

```
  # Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
  # or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
  # distributed with this work for additional information
  # regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
  # to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
  # "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
  # with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
  #
  #     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
  #
  # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  # limitations under the License.

  calculate_heap_sizes()
  {
    case "`uname`" in
     Linux)
        system_memory_in_mb=`free -m | awk '/:/ {print $2;exit}'`
        system_cpu_cores=`egrep -c 'processor([[:space:]]+):.*' /proc/cpuinfo`
    ;;
    FreeBSD)
        system_memory_in_bytes=`sysctl hw.physmem | awk '{print $2}'`
        system_memory_in_mb=`expr $system_memory_in_bytes / 1024 / 1024`
        system_cpu_cores=`sysctl hw.ncpu | awk '{print $2}'`
    ;;
    SunOS)
        system_memory_in_mb=`prtconf | awk '/Memory size:/ {print $3}'`
        system_cpu_cores=`psrinfo | wc -l`
    ;;
    Darwin)
        system_memory_in_bytes=`sysctl hw.memsize | awk '{print $2}'`
        system_memory_in_mb=`expr $system_memory_in_bytes / 1024 / 1024`
        system_cpu_cores=`sysctl hw.ncpu | awk '{print $2}'`
    ;;
    *)
        # assume reasonable defaults for e.g. a modern desktop or
        # cheap server
        system_memory_in_mb="2048"
        system_cpu_cores="2"
    ;;
   esac

     .....................
```

This is default cassandra-env.sh from dse4.5.2

When i start cassandra it says,

```
  : not foundinstallables/dse-4.5.2/resources/cassandra/bin/cassandra: 16:  
  /usr/local/installables/dse-4.5.2/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra-
  env.sh:

  : not foundinstallables/dse-4.5.2/resources/cassandra/bin/cassandra: 18: 
  /usr/local/installables/dse-4.5.2/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra-
  env.sh: {

  /usr/local/installables/dse-4.5.2/resources/cassandra/bin/cassandra: 19: 
  /usr/local/installables/dse-4.5.2/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra-
  env.sh: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "in")
```

I can see "in" after case. What does this error indicate? Any help?

Comment: From http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/debugging.html - "Error messages may disregard comment lines in a script when reporting the line number of a syntax error" - I think we need some more context.

Comment: Thanks Peter. you mean do u need more program code? I din't get any error messages other than this.

Comment: If the line numbers are disregarding the comments then we need to see more of the script so we can see about 20 lines of non-comment code. Make sure you are getting it from /usr/local/installables/dse-4.5.2/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh and not from any other location

Comment: Yes Peter I checked the location also and update dthe question

Answer (score 2):

Check the line endings.

Windows uses CR LF (^M^J) to mark the end of a line. Unix-like systems use just LF (^J).

In a script with Windows-style line endings, the `^M` characters will be interpreted as part of a word, not as whitespace. For example, a line that looks like:

```
foo
```

might actually be:

```
foo^M
```

(where ^M is the carriage return character that introduces a Windows-style line ending).  The shell, rather than executing the command `foo` (which presumably exists) will try and fail to execute `foo^M`, which doesn't.  The error message:

```
foo^M: Command not found
```

will look like:

```
: Command not found
```

because when the ^M is printed it sends the cursor to the beginning of the line, causing part of the error message to be overwritten.

Use `unix2dos` or `tr -d '\r'` to fix the line endings.  (Read the man page for `unix2dos` first; unlike most Unix filter program, it replaces its input file by default rather than writing to standard output.)

Comment: Thanks Thompson. Let me try this.